# How to install GraalVM with Python?

Tags: python, java, maven, graalvm

I wanted to test the [GraalVM project](https://github.com/hpi-swa-lab/graalpython-java-example). I firstly installed [graalvm-jdk-21.0.1+12.1](https://www.graalvm.org/downloads/); however, in the step where I had to run the command '"${JAVA_HOME}"/bin/gu install python', I run into trouble.  There was no /bin/gu file inside the "graalvm-jdk-21.0.1+12.1" directory.

I then installed [graalvm-jdk-17.0.9+11.1](https://www.graalvm.org/downloads/) which contained /bin/gu file. But this time I run into another issue which was:
[Python not available](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RhCbr.png)

I tried to skip this step and run "mvn compile" and it gave the error below:
`

```
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time:  0.623 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2023-10-18T15:08:57+04:00
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-enforcer-plugin:3.0.0-M3:enforce (enforce-graalvm-python) on project PygalExample: org.apache.maven.plugins.enforcer.RequireFilesExist failed with message:
[ERROR] You must set JAVA_HOME to a GraalVM with Python installed.
[ERROR] Some required files are missing:
[ERROR] /home/eshqin/Downloads/graalvm-jdk-17_linux-x64_bin/graalvm-jdk-17.0.9+11.1/bin/graalpython
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] -> [Help 1]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoExecutionException
```

How can I solve this issue and replicate the test? When I run "mvn clean install" it also fails.

My operating system is Ubuntu 20.04

I would like this project to be compiled and run successfully.

Comment: The word _"crash"_  has a specific meaning (terminating abruptly), and in this case Maven didn't _"crash"_, it exited with an error because a precondition of a plugin wasn't met (i.e. _"You must set JAVA_HOME to a GraalVM with Python installed."_), and that plugin reported the error to Maven, and then Maven reported that error to you.

Comment: It was my first time to ask question. I sometimes am not well aware of exact terminology. Thank you for correction.

Comment: “ You must set JAVA_HOME to a GraalVM with Python installed.” - sounds like you can’t skip that step.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The latest release of GraalVM (GraalVM for JDK21) changes how languages are deployed. There is no `gu` (Graal Updater) and GraalPy is not installed into the GraalVM installation, but instead it is published on Mavencentral. The `pom.xml` script in the article assumes older version of GraalVM. We will update the article.

For the time being, this is a new article about the changes:

https://medium.com/graalvm/truffle-unchained-13887b77b62c

you'd have to modify `pom.xml` from the old GraalPy article accordingly. Another alternative is to use the new GraalPy's `standalone` tool to generate a skeleton of Java app:

https://www.graalvm.org/latest/reference-manual/python/standalone-binaries/#embedding-graalpy-in-a-java-application